# Recover active config from memory in FreeRADIUS?

Tags: linux, freeradius

I have a problem on one of my FreeRADIUS servers. I got a corrupted configfile for one of my virtual servers due to the disk going full mid-write. Normally I would just pull the file from Veeam backup, but my backup guy just told me this particular server was forgotten and ironically tomorrow this server was to be added to puppet for config management. *Sigh*

Before I spend a week tracing old files on other servers which might have parts of the config missing due to early tests etc I was wondering if there is a way to recover the config from memory. The server is working as it has not rebooted or restarted since the write-error, but as soon as that happens it will fail.

Any ideas?

The server is Centos 7, FreeRADIUS version is 3.0.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeRADIUS doesn't allow you to dump the config from a running process. The configuration files are not stored in buffers in memory, they're parsed into C structures which represent nesting, attributes and values.

Comment: Ack... I was afraid of something like that... Thank you for answering so fast.